# How to use Cognito identity pool with UnAuthenticatd users in Amplify for Android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I've been going through the AWS Amplify [docs and tutorials](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/getting-started/q/platform/android) for how to use Amplify and Cognito identity pools together with UNauthenticated users. The example given by the Amplify docs is:

```
Amplify.Auth.fetchAuthSession(
    result -> {
        AWSCognitoAuthSession cognitoAuthSession = (AWSCognitoAuthSession) result;
            switch(cognitoAuthSession.getIdentityId().getType()) {
                case SUCCESS:
                    Log.i("AuthQuickStart", "IdentityId: " + cognitoAuthSession.getIdentityId().getValue());
                    break;
                case FAILURE:
                    Log.i("AuthQuickStart", "IdentityId not present because: " + cognitoAuthSession.getIdentityId().getError().toString());
            }
        },
        error -> Log.e("AuthQuickStart", error.toString())
);
```

But in practice when I use this code - I get an error printed out in LogCat:

```
AuthQuickStart: FAILURE IdentityId not present because: AmplifyException {message=You are currently signed out., cause=null, recoverySuggestion=Please sign in and reattempt the operation.}
```

Note: I did configure AWS Cognito to support Unauthenticaed users!

I've also looked everywhere for the Amplify Android API doc to see what other APIs are supported - couldn't find any Android API docs.
And looking into the AWS `Amplify.Auth` methods i could not find ANY function that deals with unauthenticated users

**Question:**

**Any clue how can i use Amplify (Android) and have AWS credentials via AWS Cognito for unauthenticated users ???**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is David from the Amplify Android team. I was actually just looking into this the other day and currently there's a hack that's required to make unauth users work.

After setting up unauth/guest users through the CLI (as you mentioned you had) you have to call the `getAWSCredentials` method on the underlying escape hatch once for the app to get it to work.

Here's a code snippet I'd written that you can run after `Amplify.configure` (and again, this only needs to be run once per app install):

```java
AWSMobileClient mobileClient = (AWSMobileClient) Amplify.Auth.getPlugin("awsCognitoAuthPlugin").getEscapeHatch();

mobileClient.getAWSCredentials(new Callback<AWSCredentials>() {
     @Override
     public void onResult(AWSCredentials result) {

        // Now you'll see the Identity ID and AWSCredentials in the resulting auth session object.
        Amplify.Auth.fetchAuthSession(
            result2 -> Log.i(TAG, result2.toString()),
            error -> Log.e(TAG, error.toString()));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }

     @Override
     public void onError(Exception e) {
          // Handle the error however is best for your app
     }
});
```

I'm working on a solution to avoid this hack right now and adding a documentation section on Unauth users to our site but in the meantime this should get it working for you.

Again note you only have to do this once and from then on out, it should just work when you call `fetchAuthSession`.

**UPDATE: The non patched (official) version:**

```java
Amplify.Auth.fetchAuthSession(
    result -> {
        AWSCognitoAuthSession cognitoAuthSession = (AWSCognitoAuthSession) result;
        switch (cognitoAuthSession.getIdentityId().getType()) {
            case SUCCESS:
                Log.i(TAG, "identity: " + cognitoAuthSession.getIdentityId().getValue());
                Log.i(TAG, "credentials: " + cognitoAuthSession.getAWSCredentials().getValue(););
                break;
            case FAILURE:
                Log.i(TAG, "FAILURE IdentityId not present because: " + cognitoAuthSession.getIdentityId().getError().toString());
        }
    },
    error -> Log.e(TAG, "UNAUTH USERS ERR: " + error.toString()));
```

Comment: Checked, that works!
Now I do get an identityId and credentials for the unauthenticated user. (although I still see in the logcat "you are currently signed out ... Please sign in and reattempt the operation").

Its very important to note - for having unauthenticated users use AWS services (e.g. s3, kinesis etc.) no authentication code is required (not even the one you posted above), 
just go ahead and use Amplify sdk Kinesis code as usual (of course if you had setup the unauthenticated role to use Kinesis in the AWS console).

Comment: I will highly appreciate if the Amplify android page will include the (non patched) example when this development is done.
And please note that there are alot of client examples (e.g. Kinesis) on the sdk obsolete pages (https://docs.amplify.aws/sdk/analytics/kinesis/q/platform/android) which do not appear at all on the current amplify sdk documentation (https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/analytics/personalize/q/platform/js#working-with-the-api)

Comment: Yup I've actually already written the updated documentation which is scheduled to go out when my patch (which is now done as well) is released this week or next.

Comment: Alright it's now live in the latest version of Amplify and the documentation is updated here: https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/guest_access/q/platform/android

Comment: Validated it, everything works fine now. Thanks for the support

Comment: how to get sessionToken ? it's needed in postman when using temporary credentials (together with secret and access keys). i used `AWSCognitoAuthSession cognitoAuthSession = (AWSCognitoAuthSession) result; String sessionToken = ((AWSSessionCredentials) mobileClient.getCredentials()).getSessionToken();` it worked but now get `assumed-role/amplify-xxxxxx-unauthRole/CognitoIdentityCredentials is not authorized to perform: execute-api:Invoke on resource:`

Comment: So as a Guest user you have a separate IAM role than when you are signed in which it sounds like doesn't have the permission needed to do what you're trying to do. You'd need to edit the IAM role to give it that permission if you wanted to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You wont be able to retrieve an authenticated session unless you have a logged in user.

If your Identity Pool (not User Pool) is configured for unauthenticated or guest users you can make a simple call to the `GetId` endpoint:

### GetId

Generates (or retrieves) a Cognito ID. Supplying multiple logins will create an implicit linked account.

This is a public API. You do not need any credentials to call this API.

Request Syntax

```
{
   "AccountId": "string",
   "IdentityPoolId": "string",
   "Logins": { 
      "string" : "string" 
   }
}
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognitoidentity/latest/APIReference/API_GetId.html

You should then be able to use the ID to retrieve a token using:

### GetOpenIdToken

Gets an OpenID token, using a known Cognito ID. This known Cognito ID is returned by GetId. You can optionally add additional logins for the identity. Supplying multiple logins creates an implicit link.

The OpenID token is valid for 10 minutes.

This is a public API. You do not need any credentials to call this API.

Request Syntax

```
{
   "IdentityId": "string",
   "Logins": { 
      "string" : "string" 
   }
}
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognitoidentity/latest/APIReference/API_GetOpenIdToken.html